# Implicit Makefile Targets

Tags: makefile

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/makefiles_continued.html explains implicit targets:

> There are some actions that are nearly ubiquitous: for instance, you might have a collection of .c files that you may wish to execute the same command for. Ideally, the name of the file would be the target; using the implicit target ".c" you can specify a command to execute for any target that corresponds to the name of a .c file (minus the .c extension).

However, when I try it, the implicit target is simply ignored.  My test makefile is as follows:

```
Default: Foo.bar
    echo "In default."

.bar:
    echo "In .bar."
```

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Foo.bar', needed by `Default'.  Stop.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm the webmaster over at cprogramming.com. I just wanted to mention that Max very kindly reported this error to me, and I've updated the original tutorial to remove the erroneous description of to implicit targets and also the recommendation to use them at all (it already mentioned pattern rules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
default: foo.bar
    echo "In default."

%.bar:
    echo "In .bar."
```

You may be asking about old-style suffix rules - for example this rule:

```
.c.o:
    cc -c $<
```

tells make  how to build a .o file from a .c source. The form with the '%' is known as a pattern rules and is more "modern". I suggest you read the [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), which is very informative about such stuff, and easy to read.

Comment: That's what I've been using, but the website's example just has `.bar`.  Is the website incorrect?